How to run a local python script with spark on mesos in cluster mode
I want to run a local python script with spark on mesos.
My master use a mesos dispatcher to install a spark framework.
./start-mesos-dispatcher.sh --master mesos://master:5050 

Then I use spark-submmit to submit a python script stored in file system to cluster.
./bin/spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster                 \
                   --master mesos://master:7077          \
                   --conf spark.master.rest.enabled=true \
                   /home/ryneli/test.py

My python script
#!env/python3 -u

print("HIHI")

I can successfully submit the task. But the task is always failed. I check the sandbox stderr in mesos, it says:
I0904 00:54:39.493541 128305 logging.cpp:466] Logging to STDERR
I0904 00:54:39.493642 128305 fetcher.cpp:562] Fetcher Info: {"cache_directory":"/tmp/mesos/fetch/ryneli","items":[{"action":"BYPASS_CACHE","uri":{"cache":false,"extract":true,"value":"/home/ryneli/test.py"}}],"sandbox_directory":"agent_dir/slaves/61638c6a-c12e-4b93-93bd-ac3a50f84fcc-S0/frameworks/61638c6a-c12e-4b93-93bd-ac3a50f84fcc-0000/executors/driver-20240904005417-0001/runs/133f7532-a5bd-4402-91e2-265e8bf6b238","stall_timeout":{"nanoseconds":60000000000},"user":"ryneli"}
I0904 00:54:39.502841 128305 fetcher.cpp:459] Fetching URI '/home/ryneli/test.py'
I0904 00:54:39.502864 128305 fetcher.cpp:290] Fetching '/home/ryneli/test.py' directly into the sandbox directory
E0904 00:54:39.507786 128305 fetcher.cpp:615] EXIT with status 1: Failed to fetch '/home/ryneli/test.py': `destination` was a relative path
Failed to synchronize with agent (it's probably exited)

The error is because my agent server cannot access the file.
My master server shares files with my agent server with NFS, is it possible to let my agent server run this python script?

Your Spark code should probably import and actually use Spark code, not just print something. If you want to run Python code on Mesos on its own, then you don't need Spark for that

This is a demo script. I will put Spark code in the file if the flow can work.

The file(s) must be uploaded to shared filesystem first. Have you tried using nfs://path/to/file.py as the file submission?

My agent can access the file with exactly same absolute path, so the files is there. I am just wondering why Spark cannot fetch that script.

I followed your suggestion. Now the error message is "Failed to create HDFS client: Hadoop client is not available". It seem like I still need to use Hadoop and HDFS.

HDFS is not required. But the Hadoop client is used to read any filesystem. The docs suggest using local:/ but then that assumes you have NFS mounted by some external program on all the nodes at some common location. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#advanced-dependency-management Otherwise, Absolute paths and file:/ URIs are served by the driver’s HTTP file server, and every executor pulls the file from the driver HTTP server. So, you get an error since the driver isn't running an accessible HTTP server.

Thanks for your help. I will investigate Hadoop client.

It's built into Spark. Usually don't have to configure much for it
